# What's the purpose of "by" in "Stop back by"?

Tags: grammar

These are transcriptions from Sling Blade (1996):

> - Bill, I'll see you.
> - Okay. Stop back **by**.

What's the purpose of "by"?

Comment: Which region was the speaker from? In my General American English, I wouldn’t say, “Stop back by,” although “Stop by,” and “Walk on by,” are both common. But it sounds charming.

Comment: @Davislor Southern American (Redneck)

Comment: @Davislor: Rural deep American South (Arkansas).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Stop by" is used idiomatically as a *phrasal verb* meaning "visit briefly", e.g. "stop by Bill's house" means "visit Bill's house briefly". (You can't really analyse "by" separately; literally, it would mean "stop next to", but that's not what is understood.)

Meanwhile, "back" here refers to *returning*, e.g. "Go back to Bill's house" means "go to Bill's house again, which you've been to before".

The sentence is missing a mention of any place, so it is assumed by context to be "here", most likely the speaker's house or office.

So, "Stop back by" is a short and colloquial way to say "Please visit me here again in future".

Comment: I've never heard "stop back by"

Comment: @user253751 Well, you have now :)

Comment: *Stop by* **can** be brief, but I'd probably describe it more as *casual*. So you might just be popping in to say hi, or you might visit unannounced and stay for a while. I *think* the "by" part might be in the sense of "on your way to somewhere else" - if you think what *pass by* means, and then what *stop* implies instead of *pass*, I feel like that makes sense! I haven't researched it though.

Comment: @cactustictacs Prepositions tend to be quite flexible in their range of meanings, but the comparison to "pass by" sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: Just fyi - Idioms such as "stop by", which combine a verb and a preposition into a phrase with a different meaning, are known as [phrasal verbs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrasal%20verb)

Comment: @Caledon Ah, thanks, I had a feeling there was a technical term for it, but could only think of "separable verbs" in German and Dutch. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Okay. Stop back by.

This is short for something like, "Stop back by **my house**". Or wherever Bill is. It's an invitation to come back and visit me again.

Comment: I think OP knows what it means, and was wondering how that works grammatically.  Your expanded form has the same question.